# Select only one checkbox/radiobutton in the same row and column with Two checkbox/Radio button in a row using Listview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I have used Customized Listview using Adapter class in the Adapter class Two checkbox in a ROW For this I need Select Only one check box Either Checkbox1 Row/Column same  as Checkbox 2.
For Example I have 5 rows in a Listview Totally 10 Checkbox inside Listview Out 10 Only one select at a Time all Other should  unselect

Any idea About that I tried Lot but select only Checkbox1 column only 
Please help

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {

    private List<Friend> myFriends;
    private Activity activity;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;
    String flag="";

    String[]ids=new String[100];
    String[]ids1=new String[100];

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Friend> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
        this.myFriends = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);  // This line is important.
        holder.checkBox1.setTag(position + 100);
        holder.friendName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        holder.rdgrp.setTag(position);

        ids[position]=holder.checkBox.getTag().toString();
        ids1[position]=holder.rdgrp.getTag().toString();
        // System.out.println("praveen"+ids[position]);
        if (position == selectedPosition) {
            holder.rdgrp.setActivated(true);
        } else holder.rdgrp.setActivated(false);

        if( holder.checkBox.getTag().equles(position)){
            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox, position));
        }else{
            holder.checkBox1.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox1, position));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onStateChangedListener(final RadioGroup gry, final int position ){
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (gry.isClickable()) {
                    selectedPosition = position;
                } else {
                    selectedPosition = -1;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView friendName;
        private CheckBox checkBox,checkBox1;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check);
            checkBox1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check1);
            friendName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: yes i posted my code in below the question just now

Comment: could u please help me any one

Answer (score 0):

you can use group for check box of a single row of list view which has two check box and then apply following line of code

```
 "listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)"
```

Comment: i have one doubt  how to call this method  for Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 2. its working on only checkbox 1 
 public View.OnClickListener onStateChangedListener(final CheckBox ry, final int position ){
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (gry.isClickable()) {
                    selectedPosition = position;
                } else {
                    selectedPosition = -1;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    int selectedPosition = -1; // row position
    int selectedCheckbox = -1; // 1 for 1st, 2 for 2nd on each row

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(position == selectedPosition){
            if(selectedCheckbox == 1){
                checkbox1.setChecked(true);
                checkbox2.setChecked(false);
            } else if(selectedCheckbox == 2){
                chkbox1.setChecked(false);
                chkbox2.setChecked(true);
            }
        } else{
            checkbox1.setChecked(false);
            checkbox2.setChecked(false);
        }

        checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    selectedPosition = position;
                    selectedCheckbox = 1;
                } else{
                    selectedPosition = -1;
                    selectedCheckbox = -1;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    selectedPosition = position;
                    selectedCheckbox = 2;
                } else{
                    selectedPosition = -1;
                    selectedCheckbox = -1;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Hope, it will help you!